How to Add a Telegram Bot as an Admin to a Group Without Redirecting Users?
I'm working on a Telegram bot and I want to allow users to add my bot to their group as an admin.
Currently, my implementation redirects users to a link where they need to add the bot manually.
However, I noticed another bot that allows users to choose a group and adds the bot as an admin without redirecting to a link. It shows a confirmation message within Telegram itself, like this:
 
First one is my implementation. Second is the other bot.
How can I implement this functionality where users can choose the group and grant admin permissions without external redirections?
Any guidance or code examples on handling this within the Telegram Bot API would be greatly appreciated.
Here's my current code:
const setupScene = new BaseScene('setup');

setupScene.enter((ctx) => {
    const botUsername = ctx.botInfo.username;
    const deepLink = `https://telegram.me/${botUsername}?startgroup=setup&admin=change_info+delete_messages+restrict_members+invite_users+pin_messages+promote_members`;

    ctx.reply('To set up a portal, please add me to your group as an admin using the button below:', {
        reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: [[
                { text: 'Add bot to group', url: deepLink }
            ]]
        }
    });
});

